# Why is it returning this command when it shouldn't? 'numpy.ufunc' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators, finance

I am currently trying to write a Code to define an equation where one Input is set under two conditions, but I am getting an error:

```
def findV (v_a,x,k,sig_a):
    taxcorp=0.2
    taxdiv=0.2
    Modelequity=(e_function(v_a=v_a,sig_a=sig_a, r=rf, k=k,C=Intexp,taxcorp=0.2,taxdiv=0.2)+20, taxcorp, taxdiv)
    #np.logical_and(Model>0,Model<x):
    #all([Model>0 , Model<x]):
    Model=np.float32(Modelequity[0])
    #Model=np.logical_and[Model>0,Model<x]
    if np.logical_and[Model>0,Model<x]:
        #return((Equity-np.float32(Modelequity))*np.float32(Modelequity))
        return((Equity-Model)*Model)
findV(v_a=0.01,x=0.02,k=0.02,sig_a=0.02)
```

I am getting these Errors:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  if __name__ == '__main__':
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

and

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Typo: You need parentheses in `np.logical_and(Model>0,Model<x)`

Comment: Tried this before. It's actually not working..

Comment: It should fix this error. If it's not doing what you want, that's a logic error.

Comment: I put it like this now and it's telling me 
```
if np.logical_and((Model>0),(Model<x)):
```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What are you expecting? `np.logical_and()` returns an array in the same shape as `Model`.

Comment: There are lots of questions about that error message. Search for it and you'll find a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the brackets you're using. See how in the error it's referring to subscripting, which is using `[]` instead of `()`.

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object is not subscriptable:
    if np.logical_and[Model>0,Model<x]:
```

Using parentheses `()` will call a function instead of attempting to subscript it:

```py
if np.logical_and(Model>0,Model<x):
```